# Using Vue Components in Moqui Screens

Tags: vue.js, moqui

Is it possible to use VusJS Components into Moqui Screens? 
I know for sure that you can render Basic HTML but I wasn't able to find a hook for the VueJS app.

The need comes from the following scenario:
While **form-single** widget can be made collapsible, **form-list** cannot. So I wanted to use **vue-collapsible** (https://github.com/vue-comps/vue-collapsible) but I don't know where I am supposed to register the component.

If there's no way to use vue, maybe you can help me with my concrete issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 'vuet' render mode which is used in the /vapps path (as opposed to /apps) it isn't actually HTML sent to the client it is a Vue Template. If you look at the text returned by the server you'll see a number of Vue Components already being used (see the WebrootVue.js file for their source). You can see this in Chrome using the Sources or Network tab in the tools window or similar tools in other browsers. If you inspect an element you'll be looking at the rendered HTML, ie after Vue runs the components to change the Vue Template to HTML.

This means that if you include the necessary JavaScript file(s), and CSS file(s) if needed, then you can use any Vue component in the Vue Template returned. You can do this inline in XML Screen files using the render-mode.text element with the @type=vuet.

None of this runs under NPM in the way VueJS is used in Moqui Framework through XML Screens. In other words it isn't a pre-packaged Vue app with 100% client/browser rendering but rather is a hybrid client and server rendered approach.

You can include scripts in this Moqui hybrid approach using the script element with a @src attribute for the script file which the WebrootVue.js file loads on the fly. There are various examples of this for additional JS scripts like Chart.JS